# Prevent a user from deleting, moving or renaming a file

Tags: c#, move, delete-file, file-rename

What I am trying to do is while my program is using a file, I want to keep the user from renaming, deleting, or moving the file (well... a move is a delete and a create at a different location according to Windows [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), but I digress).

It has been suggested that I use [FileStream.Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx) or use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx). However, FileStream.Lock seems only to prevent the file from being modified *which I am trying to allow*. Also, I am very unsure as to if a mutex can lock a file, although I am still reading on it with in the .Net 4.0 library.

Does anyone have any advice on utilizing either one and if there is a code based solution to this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you are opening the file, you can specify the sharing mode.

Opening the file with [FileAccess.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) gives you the ability to read the file, while [FileShare.ReadWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) allows the file to continue to be edited, but not deleted or moved.

```
var fs = File.Open(@"C:\temp\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
MessageBox.Show("File Locked");  // While the messagebox is up, try to open or delete the file.
// Do your work here
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Wow, this even prevents file renames. Thanks for this, this will work better than I thought, as it even throws up the Microsoft Boxes :D

Answer (score 3):

This will prevent moving or deleting the file but allows read and write:

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\TestDir\Test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        // Do Stuff.
    }
```

FileStream.Lock is actually a range lock which prevents modification of a particular portion of a file while the lock is held.