# Lock file using C#

Tags: c#, file, attributes, filesystems, rename

I saw this question: [Prevent a user from deleting, moving or renaming a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318663/prevent-a-user-from-deleting-moving-or-renaming-a-file-in-c-sharp), but it doesn't meet my needs.
If I understood correctly, as long as that stream is opened, the file is locked.

I want to have a list of files in my computer, inside some folder, that **cannot be edited, or renamed**.
The edit prevention is easy - I just set `System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly`  (Works well)

Now I need to **prevent a rename** of a files and directories

Comment: You could simply use the rights system built into whatever file system you are using. (that's what it's for)

Comment: readonly still allows file rename, plus I need to make sure folders cannot be renamed as well

Comment: i'm not talking about marking a file as "read only", i'm talking about flat out denying access to a specific user, group or container

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent a user from Deleting, Moving, or Renaming a file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318663/prevent-a-user-from-deleting-moving-or-renaming-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @TimothyGroote can you provide a code/function/attribute to do it? or at least give me a keyword to search for

Comment: @AeroX Did you read something except of the title?

Comment: If you're using NTFS, this should do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451861/setting-ntfs-permissions-in-c-net

Comment: @user990635 The top voted answer on that question says that holding an open file-stream with the `FileShare.ReadWrite` permission prevents the file being renamed whilst the stream is held open

Comment: but I don't want to hold it open. this is what I said. It is just NTFS folder, containing files (many of them) that should not be renamed. I don't want to hold an open stream. I am looking in a direction of attributes or something like that

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is rename or move are both delete operations at the core. You could try to catch and prevent instead. I'm not sure you can really do what you want to do there doesn't seem to be a flag for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx

This might help.
[How to prevent or intercept a call to Directory.Delete(path, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277559/how-to-prevent-or-intercept-a-call-to-directory-deletepath-true)

Comment: JFI: Renaming within one filesystem is a separate operation, not deletion.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Can you expand on this. Do you mean path/folder when you say filesystem? Is that in both NTFS and FAT? I know NTFS is a Journaling System so that make sense but FAT isn't how would it work in that cause. Not disagreeing just want to learn more.

Comment: Filesystem driver receives different requests from the OS to perform various operations. There exist operations such as "Open file", "write to file", "delete file". And also there's a "move file" operation present, where old and new filenames are parameters to the operation. The filenames include paths, but the paths must be within the same filesystem. I.e. if you rename file \PathA\File1 to file \PathB\File2, there's no command to delete File1 - it's renamed/moved and not deleted.